# Why does the border add a scrollbar (overflow)?

Tags: html, css

The first picture has a scrollbar, and the second doesn't.

The change is in the `.tabulator` CSS class i.e. the border rule.

Why does **just** the 1px border affect the scroll, and not the whole content?

[image]

Here's the HTML structure...

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navigation"></div>
            <div id="content-full" class="tabulator"></div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Could you provide your code as text and not as screenshots? And just a hunch: `* { box-sizing: border-box; }` perhaps?

Comment: Huh, that fixed it wtf? What's the deal? Can you please add it as an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can solve this by applying a box-sizing: border-box style rule to your elements as such:

```
* {
   box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

By default content-box is defined (only content) so border-box will make the border be included in the box context.

Alternatively, you could restructure the code to have a wrapper element where you apply the overflow and the border would be applied to the child element.

Have a read at [Formatting Contexts](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flow_Layout/Intro_to_formatting_contexts) (namely the block context) and [box-sizing CSS rule](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing)